# why analytics.js made pageview go down so much?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics.js

my old ga.js code is:

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXX-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mywebsite.com']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function(){
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

after I upgrade to new analytics.js code like this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXX-1', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

I notice that my **pageview is decreasing about 30% ~ 50%**, 
and **bounce rate is increasing about 130%**

the obvious difference syntax between old and new is:

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'mywebsite.com']);
```

as far as I know, actually there is no sub domain site,
I guess maybe the old analytics data is incorrect,
and the new analytics data is correct?

is there anyone can explain why the analytics data change so big?
or what am I doing wrong with?

Comment: This question looks like it would be a better fit on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: maybe you forgot to implement new GA on every page?

Comment: no, 
the old syntax is in a xxx.js file,
I replace the old syntax with the new syntax in this xxx.js file